# There are two events that we have defined, app_update and app_remove. Is this a known issue?

Tags: android

I am using Firebase to track the analytics for our android Beta application. There are two events that we have defined, app_update and app_remove. The number of users that updated to the latest version is shown to be less than the ones who deleted it. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

The two events `app_update` and `app_remove` will automatically be recorded if you integrate firebase in your app.

`app_update` will be recorded if the user updates the app to an higher version and `app_delete` will be recorded if the user uninstalls the app.

There is no relation between these two events. They are independent of each other.